# How to improve my "random words cloud" function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wrote simple js function which outputs words or phrases from an array in random coordinates of canvas area.

But i've confused in my algorithm or styles, the words appers in random coordinates and cover each other. How improve my function or styles to avoid this issue?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  words();
});

// Words array
function words() {
  var words = ["lorem ipsum dolor sit amet", "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet", "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet", "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet", "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet", "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet", "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet", "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet", "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet", "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet", "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet", "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet", "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"];

  $.each(words, function(index, value) {
    // console.log( index + ": " + value );
    $('#words_block').append('<div class="word"><span>' + value + '</span></div>');
  });

  // callback wuth check
  if (typeof wordsCloud != 'undefined' && $.isFunction(wordsCloud)) {
    return wordsCloud();
  } else {
    alert('wordsCloud() does not exist');
  }
}

// Words effects
function wordsCloud() {
  var maxDelay = 2000;
  var minSpeed = 2500;
  var maxSpeed = 4000;

  $('#words_block .word').each(function() {
    var delay = Math.ceil(Math.random() * maxDelay);
    var speed = maxSpeed + Math.ceil(Math.random() * (minSpeed - maxSpeed));

    var random_num_two = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101);
    var random_num_three = Math.floor(Math.random() * (0 - 700) + 700);
    var random_text_size = Math.floor(Math.random() * (14 - 55) + 55);

    $(this).delay(delay).css({
      "font-size": random_text_size + 'px',
      top: random_num_three + 'px',
      left: random_num_two + '%'

      // opacity from .1 to .6
    }).fadeTo(speed, (Math.random() * (0.1 - 0.7) + 0.7).toFixed(2));
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
#words_block {
  cursor: default;
  position: relative;
  height: 700px;
  width: 900px;
}
#words_block .word {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}
#words_block .word:hover {
  z-index: 10;
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
#words_block .word:hover span {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="words_block"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ajf5nkp8/17/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either store the location of each "randomly" place string and make sure they don't overlap by checking for collisions.

```
function(rect1_x, rect1_y, rect1_w, rect1_h,
                         rect2_x, rect2_y, rect2_w, rect2_h)
{

    // top-left corner
    if ( this.PointInRect(rect1_x, rect1_y, rect2_x, rect2_y, rect2_w, rect2_h) ){return true;}
    // top-right corner
    if ( this.PointInRect(rect1_x + rect1_w - 1, rect1_y, rect2_x, rect2_y, rect2_w, rect2_h) ){return true;}
    // bottom-right corner
    if ( this.PointInRect(rect1_x + rect1_w - 1, rect1_y + rect1_h - 1, rect2_x, rect2_y, rect2_w, rect2_h) ){return true;}
    // bottom-left corner
    if ( this.PointInRect(rect1_x, rect1_y + rect1_h - 1, rect2_x, rect2_y, rect2_w, rect2_h) ){return true;}
    // Check to see if rectangle 2 is hit any part of rectanlge 1
    // top-left corner
    if ( this.PointInRect(rect2_x, rect2_y, rect1_x, rect1_y, rect1_w, rect1_h) ){return true;}
    // top-right corner
    if ( this.PointInRect(rect2_x + rect2_w - 1, rect2_y, rect1_x, rect1_y, rect1_w, rect1_h) ){return true;}
    // bottom-right corner
    if ( this.PointInRect(rect2_x + rect2_w - 1, rect2_y + rect2_h - 1, rect1_x, rect1_y, rect1_w, rect1_h) ){return true;}
    // bottom-left corner
    if ( this.PointInRect(rect2_x, rect2_y + rect2_h - 1, rect1_x, rect1_y, rect1_w, rect1_h) ){return true;}
    // If there is no collision
    return false;
}
```

Or you could draw a solid box around each string with opacity set to 25% which will cover the other strings behind it which may give a better feel and style.

Comment: thank you for answer, but where i get all thes coordinates stuff?

Comment: what you will have to do is create a new object for each string you draw and store the random X and Y position and to workout the height and width you can use `measureText()`